# Why some system calls shield SIGPROF signal under strace

Tags: c, linux, strace

When I strace this code

```c
void printMsg();

int main() {
  signal(SIGPROF, printMsg);

  struct itimerval tick;
  memset(&tick, 0, sizeof(tick));

  tick.it_value.tv_sec = 1;  // sec
  tick.it_value.tv_usec = 0; // micro sec.
  tick.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  tick.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

  setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &tick, NULL);

  while(1) {
    ;
  }

  return 0;
}

void printMsg() {
    printf("%s","Hello World!!\n");
}
```

I got the `SIGPROF` signal after 1 second as expected

```
...
05:54:10 setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={1, 0}}, NULL) = 0
05:54:11 --- SIGPROF {si_signo=SIGPROF, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
...
```

But when I add a system call like `write(2, "", 0)` or `read(2, "", 0)` in `while(1)` and strace again,  it looks like `SIGPROF` can not be fired. However, `time(0)` in `while(1)` can trigger SIGPROF properly.

Btw, I use this code to emulate following PHP script, which ignored time limit under PHP-FPM SAPI,

```php
<?php
set_time_limit(5);  // PHP uses setitimer(ITIMER_PROF) to implement this function
while (true) {
    flush();       // PHP uses write(<fd>, "", 0) to implement this function
}
```

Comment: How do you get the output format? I mean what system/compiler/tool you use. Could you say? By the bye, I added `write(1, STDIN_FILENO, 12);` in the `while` loop and caught the signal.

Comment: Note that your signal handler function `printMsg()` is not safe.  You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler. `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.  On Linux, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: @snr yes, `write(1, STDIN_FILENO, 12);` works. I wrote `while (1) write(2, "", 0)` and I checked again, this empty `write` indeed shielded the signal `SIGPROF`.  I uses gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4)

Answer (score 1):

The code trigger the SIGPROF using ITIMER_PROF, which is counting when the process is executing, or when the system is running on behalf of the process.

When the process goes into 'read' or 'write' calls, it is not 'running'. The process goes into IO Wait (and the system will allocate the CPU  to other processes). When the process is in IOWait, the timer is not moving. When there is a system call that perform processing (mostly in system space) - e.g. time() is a tight loop, the timer will be moving.

See more about process states in https://www.tecmint.com/linux-process-management/

If you want to measure 'clock' time, consider using timer_create with CLOCK_REALTIME or CLOCK_MONOTONIC

Comment: Or use `ITIMER_REAL` with `SIGALRM`.

Comment: Is there any guarantee a process in blocking cannot receive a signal, i.e. during IO Wait? -1 from me. By the by, you should glance at my other comment. How does it work so?

Comment: I believe a process can get signals during IOWait (e.g.  SIGPIPE, SIGALRM), without going thru 'running' mode. In single threaded mode, once a signal is handled, the system call will complete with EINTR.

Comment: @snr I tried `write(1, STDIN_FILENO, 12);` and it works, but I think `write()` accepts `void* buf` as its 2nd param, not an int `#define STDIN_FILENO 0`